# i want to append the json code before closing square brackets "]"

Tags: json, bash, shell

Here is my code:

```
data='{
        "tags": "'"$name"'",
        "sequence": 1,
        "extra-vars": ""
}'
```

I want to append this data into another json file before closing square brackets.

Please suggest me the solution

```
 {
   "sprint": "132",
   "extra-vars": "",
   "roles": [
     {
       "tags": "orc-compaction",
       "sequence": 2,
       "extra-vars": ""
     },
     {
        "tags": "'"$name"'",
        "sequence": 1,
        "extra-vars": ""
     }
   ]
 }
```

Comment: Is `bash` only a requirement ? Anyway, with bash only you must use text processing that is error-prone. If you have `bash` it is most likely you have, let say, python available. With python you can process JSON data correctly.

Comment: What have you searched for and what have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: @anasuya tammana – 
What's in _another json file_?

Answer (score 0):

```
% data='{ "tags": "'"$name"'", "sequence": 1, "extra-vars": "" }'

% cat another_json_file
{ "sprint": "132", "extra-vars": "", "roles": [ { "tags": "orc-compaction", "sequence": 2, "extra-vars": "" }, { "tags": "", "sequence": 1, "extra-vars": "" } ] }

% jq ".roles += [$data]" another_json_file
{
  "sprint": "132",
  "extra-vars": "",
  "roles": [
    {
      "tags": "orc-compaction",
      "sequence": 2,
      "extra-vars": ""
    },
    {
      "tags": "",
      "sequence": 1,
      "extra-vars": ""
    },
    {
      "tags": "",
      "sequence": 1,
      "extra-vars": ""
    }
  ]
}
```